# Is there a way to use enumerate starting at a certain column?

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a for loop that goes through data frame columns starting at 2:

`for col in basis.columns[2:]:`

I want to turn it into an enumerate for loop. Kinda like this:
`for col, x in enumerate(basis):`

So that I can access the next values in the loop. (not sure if this is the best way to do it, but that's what I think works lol)

The thing is- I want to start the enumerate at the second column (The `2:` part) like in the first example. I'm not really sure how to do that :/ Any help would be really helpful! Thanks

Comment: You probably want to be avoiding the loop in the first place.

Comment: @miradulo yeah I assumed there would be a better solution but im really new :/ do you know of a better solution?

Comment: It depends - what are you actually doing inside your loop?

Comment: @miradulo I'm going to select a certain row in each column and check if the row after that has the same value. Then theres code that runs if its the same or not

Comment: Can you edit that code into your question so I can be sure I understand properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so:

```
for col, x in enumerate(basis.iloc[:,2:]):
```

Example:

```
   a  b  c
0  1  4  7
1  2  5  8
2  3  6  9

for col, x in enumerate(basis.iloc[:,2:]):
    print col, x
```

Output:

```
0 c
```